# RuntimeException SplFileInfo::getSize(): stat failed for… Laravel 6 upload image

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, file-upload, splfileobject

I work with laravel 6 (last update), I create a form where we could upload an image. I am on Windows OS, I use PHPStorm, laravel and xampp Applications. All my configuration is setting right, no running problems.

My probleme is that I have this error when I submit the reaching fields from my form:

> RuntimeException SplFileInfo::getSize(): stat failed for
>   C:\xampp\tmp\phpA5C6.tmp \

Here's the code from my form create.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
  <div class="container">


    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">Creat Post</div>
          <div class="card-body">
            @if(count($errors) > 0)
              <ul>
                @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                  <li class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show">
                    <strong>{{$error}}</strong>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                  </li>
                @endforeach
              </ul>
            @endif
            <form action="{{route('post.store')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
              @csrf
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title">Title</label>
                <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="title" aria-describedby="title" placeholder="Type Your Title">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="category">Category</label>
                  <select class="form-control" name="category_id" id="category">
                    <option value="0" selected disabled>Select A Category</option>
                    @foreach($categories as $category)
                      <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                  </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="content">Content</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="content" id="content" rows="4" cols="4" placeholder="Type Your Content"></textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="image">Image</label>
                <input type="file" name="image" id="image" class="form-control-file">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </form>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
@endsection
```

Here's the code from my controller:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $this->validate($request, [
                "title"       => "required|string",
                "content"     => "required|string",
                "category_id" => "required",
                "image"       => "required|image"
              ]);

        $file = $request->image;
        $destinationPath = public_path().'/uploads/posts';
        $filename = $destinationPath . '' . time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $uploaded = $file->move($destinationPath,$filename);


        $post = Post::create([
          "title"       => $request->title,
          "content"     => $request->content,
          "category_id" => $request->category_id,
          "image"       => $uploaded
        ]);
```

The uploaded file code works perfect, I register the file in the selected folder I want. I Have no problem with my routes (no need to show this part of the code). and the database didn't count the record from create post.

and When I submit the form, I have this error:

> RuntimeException SplFileInfo::getSize(): stat failed for
>   C:\xampp\tmp\phpA5C6.tmp

and I've checked the `upload_max_filesize` in the `php.ini` and the `UploadedFile.php` in `laravel/vendor` and they have the same value.

If you have any ideas... Thank you.

Comment: Did you get any solution I'm having same exception for image.

Answer (score 0):

I Know it is late to answer, but for other's knowledge. I've the same issue with laravel 6.

> stat failed for C:\xampp\tmp\phpA5C6.tmp \

This error points to the exact reason, It's because  the request take the temporary uploaded file with extension *.tmp*, and try to assign this value to your field in database. In your validation you force it to get only image with known extensions.
so I did these steps:

- create hidden input in blade file with the same database field name(image) in your code.

  ```
  <input type="hidden" id="image" name="image">
  ```

  and rename the file input field to some other name not related to db columns names( say some_pic)
- in your Controller, after validation, upload your file then prepare for inserting to the database

  ```
   $imageName = time().'.'.$request->some_pic->extension();
  ```

  $request->some_pic->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);

  if ($request->has('some_pic')) {
  $request->merge(['image' => $imageName]);
  }

  then you will except the file input when insert your request

  ```
  $post=Post::create($request->except('some_pic'));
  ```